# Set-up SQL processing power

Tags: postgresql, ram

I have been asked to set-up PostgreSQL in a way that uses all the processing power of my computer. I really tried searching but didn't get really far. Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: That is far too broad. Use `pg_bench` as an artificial load test and see if it can use all the resources the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent annotated `posgresql.conf` at GitHub - https://github.com/jberkus/annotated.conf